# pandas groupby count the number of zeros in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, e.g:

```
Date             B           C   
20.07.2018      10           8
20.07.2018       1           0
21.07.2018       0           1
21.07.2018       1           0
```

How can I count the zero and non-zero values for each column for each date?
Using `.sum()` doesn't help me because it will sum the non-zero values.

e.g: expected output for the zero values:

```
Date          B         C
20.07.2018    0         1
21.07.2018    1         1
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe need [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with compare by `0` and `sum`:

a) To count no. of zero values:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Date').agg(lambda x: x.eq(0).sum())
print (df1)

            B  C
Date            
20.07.2018  0  1
21.07.2018  1  1
```

b) To count no. of non-zero values:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Date').agg(lambda x: x.ne(0).sum())
print (df2)
            B  C
Date            
20.07.2018  2  1
21.07.2018  1  1
```

Another idea for improve performance is create `DatetimeIndex`, compare columns and last use `sum` per level (DatetimeIndex):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Date').eq(0).sum(level=0)
print (df1)
            B  C
Date            
20.07.2018  0  1
21.07.2018  1  1

df2 = df.set_index('Date').ne(0).sum(level=0)
print (df2)
            B  C
Date            
20.07.2018  2  1
21.07.2018  1  1
```

Comment: Thank you! can you separate this per column though?

Comment: @MGs - What is expected output?

Comment: for zero values expected output:   Date 20.07.2018  B: 0 C: 1  , 21.07.2018 B : 1, C:1

Comment: Thanks jezrael for help! could you tell also how to count the non zero values? I don't need the sum(), just the count of the non zero values. thanks a lot

Comment: @MGs - just change `eq` to `ne`

Comment: With Pandas 2.1.2, the `sum(level=0)` spits `TypeError: sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'level'`. This is consistent with the official documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html.

Answer (score 2):

Try also:

```
df.groupby('Date').agg(lambda x: len(x) - x.astype(bool).sum(axis=0))
```

Output:

```
Out[48]: 
            B  C
Date            
20.07.2018  0  1
21.07.2018  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `melt`, then `groupby`

```
Newdf=df.melt('Date')
Newdf.value=Newdf.value.eq(0).astype(int)

Newdf.groupby(['Date','variable']).value.value_counts().unstack([1,2]).sort_index(level=0,axis=1)
Out[69]: 
variable      B         C     
value         0    1    0    1
Date                          
20.07.2018  NaN  2.0  1.0  1.0
21.07.2018  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Does `20.07.2018`  have 3 counts of 0 value?

Comment: You have almost got it. I do not think you need non-zero counts. See edited question by OP with expected output.

Comment: @harvpan  *I count the zero and non zeros values*