# Iterating through pandas dataframe and appending a dictionary?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to transition from excel to python, and for practice I would like to analyze sports data from the NFL season. I have created a pandas dataframe with the data I would like to track, but I was wondering how I can go through the data and create a dictionary with each teams wins and loses. I thought that I could iterate through the dataframe and check whether or not each team has already been entered into the dictionary, and if not append their name to it.

Any advice?

`closing_lines` dataframe sample:

|  | Year | Week | side | type | line | odds | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2006 | 01 | PIT | MONEYLINE | NaN | -125.0 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2006 | 01 | MIA | MONEYLINE | NaN | 105.0 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2006 | 01 | MIA | SPREAD | 1.5 | NaN | 0.0 |
| 3 | 2006 | 01 | PIT | SPREAD | -1.5 | NaN | 1.0 |

```
results = {'Team': [], 'Wins': [], 'Losses': []}

# iterate through the data
# check to see if the dictionary has the team we are looking at 
# if it doesn't, add it to the dictionary
# if it does, add a unit to either the wins or the losses 

closing_lines = closing_lines.reset_index() #make sure that the index matches the number of rows
for index, row in closing_lines.iterrows(): 
    for key, Team in results.items(): 
        if Team == closing_lines[row, 'side']:
            pass
        else:
            results['Team'].append(closing_lines[row, 'side'])
```

Comment: For clarification, 'side' is a column in the dataframe that denotes the team.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data frame? Maybe using `closing_lines.head()`?

Comment: @Jeff    Year Week   side       type  line   odds  outcome
0  2006   01    PIT  MONEYLINE   NaN -125.0      1.0
1  2006   01    MIA  MONEYLINE   NaN  105.0      0.0
2  2006   01    MIA     SPREAD   1.5    NaN      0.0
3  2006   01    PIT     SPREAD  -1.5    NaN      1.0
4  2006   01  Under      TOTAL  34.0    NaN      0.0

Answer (score 2):

The more pandas way of doing this is to create a new data frame indexed by team with columns for wins and losses. The [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method can help with this. You can group the rows of your dataframe by team and then run some kind of summary over the results, e.g.:

```
closing_lines.groupby('side')['outcome'].sum()
```

creates a new Series indexed by 'side' with the sum of the 'outcome' column for each 'side' (which I think is Wins for this data).

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540495/pandas-groupby-count-the-number-of-zeros-in-a-column) to see how to count zeros and non-zeros in a groupby column.